# Issues Serializing an ArrayList object containing other ArrayList objects

Tags: java, arraylist, objectoutputstream

So I'm Serializing an ArrayList of ArrayLists essentially but I'm running into an issue. To be honest I'm still pretty new to Java, I've tried so many different methods to fix this as well as searched relentlessly on this site and have not been successful. I know that the way I word things may be hard to follow along or is confusing so I'll post my code here to see. Sorry in advance for all the code. SuperUsers has an arraylist of LoginInfo, PasswordKeeper has an Arraylist of SuperUsers, and the SuperUser arraylist gets serialized in PasswordKeeper. but any changes made to the LoginInfo arraylist do not save and i cannot figure out why. If anyone can help I would really Appreciate it. Thanks

```
public class PasswordKeeper{

    private ArrayList<SuperUser> users;
    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public PasswordKeeper() {
        users = new ArrayList();
    }

    public void login() {
        try {
            // reads in SuperUser arraylist
            get();
        } catch (EOFException a) {
            System.out.println("You are the First User!");
        } catch (IOException b) {
            System.out.println(b);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
        boolean loopDisplay = true;
        while (loopDisplay) {
                existingUser = keyboard.next();
                existingPass = keyboard.next();
                SuperUser temp = new SuperUser(existingUser, existingPass);
                System.out.println();
                if (users.contains(temp)) {

                    // viewing superUser method
                    temp.display();
                    //saves after method call is over
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Saving.");
                        save(users);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                }
            }
            //This happens if there is a new user
            if(answer == 2){
            SuperUser tempNew = null;
            boolean cont = true;
            String newUser;
            String pass;
            while(cont){
                newUser = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println();
                //System.out.println(users.size());

                tempNew = new SuperUser(newUser, pass);
                if(passValid(pass) == true){
                    if(makeSure(tempNew) == true){
                        System.out.println("Login Created!");
                        tempNew = new SuperUser(newUser, pass);
                        //actually being added to the arraylist
                        users.add(tempNew);
                        cont = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            //SuperUser.display method
            tempNew.display();
            try{
                System.out.println("Saving.");
                save(users);    
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
        }
    }
    //makeSure and passValid methods
    public boolean makeSure(SuperUser user){
    if(users.contains(user)){
        return false;
    }
    return true;    
}

public boolean passValid(String pass){
        boolean passes = false;
        String upper = "(.*[A-Z].*)";
        String lower = "(.*[a-z].*)";
        String numbers = "(.*[0-9].*)";
        String special = "(.*[,~,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),-,_,=,+,[,{,],},|,;,:,<,>,/,?].*$)";

        if((pass.length()>15) || (pass.length() < 8)){
            System.out.println("Entry must contain over 8 characters\n" +
            "and less than 15.");
            passes = false;
        }if(!pass.matches(upper) || !pass.matches(lower)){
            System.out.println("Entry must contain at least one uppercase and lowercase");
            passes = false;
        }if(!pass.matches(numbers)){
                    System.out.println("Password should contain atleast one number.");
                    passes = false;
        }if(!pass.matches(special)){
                    System.out.println("Password should contain atleast one special character");
                    passes = false;
        }else{
            passes = true;
        }
        return passes;
    //serializable methods
    public void save(ArrayList<SuperUser> obj) throws IOException {

        File file = new File("userInformation.dat");
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file, false);
        BufferedOutputStream buffedOutput = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOut);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(buffedOutput);
        out.writeObject(obj);
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<SuperUser> get() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("userInformation.dat");
        BufferedInputStream buffedInput = new BufferedInputStream(fileIn);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(buffedInput);
        users = (ArrayList<SuperUser>) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        fileIn.close();
        return users;
    }

    public class SuperUser implements Serializable {
        private String userName;
        private String password;
        private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        private ArrayList<LoginInfo> info = new ArrayList();

        public SuperUser(String name, String pass) {
            userName = name;
            password = pass;
        }

        public String getUser() {
            return userName;
        }

        public void display() {

            String next = keyboard.next();
            //want to add data to LoginInfo arraylist
            if (next.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
                add();
            } else if (next.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
                delete();
            } else if (numberCheck(next)) {
                int choice = (int) Integer.parseInt(next) - 1;
                edit(choice);
            //!!!! this: after doing this i lose whatever data i added
            //to the LoginInfo arraylist, right after this the
            //SuperUser arraylist gets saved. but the added data to 
            //loginInfo does not
            } else if (next.equalsIgnoreCase("logout")) {
                System.out.println(info.size());
            }
        }

        public boolean numberCheck(String in) {
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(in);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        //method to add to the Arraylist
        public void add() {
            System.out.println("What is the website name?:");
            String trash = keyboard.nextLine();
            String webName = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println("The Username?:");
            String webUsername = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println("The Password?:");
            String webPass = keyboard.nextLine();
            info.add(new LoginInfo(webUsername, webPass, webName));
            System.out.println(info.size());
            //method goes back to display
            display();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `LoginInfo Serializable`? Have you tried to put the `Scanner keyboard` outside the `SuperUser` class?

Comment: Can you cut down this code to just the few lines which illustrate your problem?  You should be able to write an example is less than 20 lines. `any changes made to the LoginInfo arraylist do not save` where are you calling save after doing this? You only appear to `save` after a successful login.

Comment: yeah the class is serializable. i took a lot out already, i just didnt want to take out too much. and Scanner is in both the PasswordKeeper and LoginInfo class. its static though in both cases so I dont believe it would change anything.. I call the save method inside password keeper after the user enters 'logout' or exits out of the SuperUser class, also i will try to edit the code more to show my issue

Comment: @Stefan I just edited the code, I removed things that were not needed to explain the issue and commented whats going on.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i removed some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
SuperUser temp = new  SuperUser(existingUser, existingPass);
    System.out.println();
    if (users.contains(temp)) {
        // viewing superUser method
        temp.display();
```

You create a temporary object which with the username and password.

Your 'users.contains()' method returns true because '.equals()' is based on the username, however the 'temp' object is a different instance to that in the list.

So when you call 'temp.display()' it is not calling on an object in the list, so no data changes will save.

You need to find the existing object from the list for that user. I would suggest that you swap your list for a map keyed on username.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list named `users`. Once you created new `SuperUser` instance (`temp`), you are checking that it belongs to this list (`users.contains(temp)`, which is false of course - from where it will occur there?). If it have belonged, the method `display` would be called, which in turn would add `LoginInfo` to that `SuperUser` (`add()` call), but I bet in reality it doesn't happened.

Also, I see where you read from `users` (check whether new `SuperUser` instances belong there), I see where you overwrite it (during desealization) but I don't see adding any instance to there, which makes me think that it is always empty.

Are you sure that `SuperUser` contains any `LoginInfo` in its array list?

Comment: Give me one moment

Comment: so i posted more code, when you create a new user, it adds an to the arraylist, then goes into the SuperUser.display method to add to the LoginInfo arraylist. once data is added to the LoginInfo arraylist it goes to SuperUser.display again, then when you type logout it goes back to PasswordKeeper.login and saves the SuperUser arrayList. but I lose the LoginInfo added data

Comment: It tells nothing, since I don't know what is inside `passValid` and `makeSure`.

Comment: added the methods it just checks that theres a certain difficulty of password used, and a unique username that doesnt already exist.

Comment: Oh, I've missed something. It changes nothing because checking for new SuperUser presence happens before its addition to the list. To be short - continuing this discussion makes no sense until you do provide a minimal reproducible example of the issue. But IMO you just have some issues in the code itself.